# Basement odor like the smell of cat pee

Tags: basement

We have a room in our basement about 14 x 20 that We use for a game room for our grandchildren now and then or a storm shelter. No plumbing, no vents, no ducts.

On Easter Sunday before the tornado we went to the basement for a couple of hours. There was no smell. The next day my son came by to hook up a generator while our power was out.

When opening the room door the odor was horrible, is smelled like strong cat pee. Cannot find where its coming from. One window and 2 doors are the only entrance.

Any suggestions on who to call.

Comment: Are you sure there were no fans venting the room?  Is there a sump pump?

Comment: If you don't have a sump and water intrusion is not bad enough to warrant adding one, try running a dehumidifier. Figure out what size you need for the space, then get the next bigger model. It won't prevent water getting in, but it'll suck that funky smell out real quick.

Answer (score 2):

If the sub floor parts of the wall is made from OSB or particle board, the glue that binds everything together is usually urea based, so when it gets wet for long enough, it spells like old pee. You my have had water intrude from underground or around window casings during the storm and got it wet. Happened to me once, I had to replace the entire floor.